# Pass Several Parameters to Url.Action under jQuery (Modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I research several post here about this topic and the best performance to me to pass several variables at `Url.Action()` / `Url.Content()` under a modal was:

```
        $('a.rengComments').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var DocID = $('#fact_num').attr('fact_num');
           var ArtID = $(this).attr('idnum');
           var TipoDoc = $(this).attr('tipo');
           var RengID = $(this).attr('rengnum');
           var DocNum = $(this).attr('docnum');          
           var url = '@Url.Content("~/PMContent/CreateRenglonComments/?id=")' + DocID + '&ArtID=' + ArtID + '&TipoDoc=' + TipoDoc + '&RengID=' + RengID + '&DocNum=' + DocNum;
        GetModal(url);            
    });


    function GetModal(url) {
        var form = $("#Modal-Charge form");
        $('#ModalContent').load(url, function (html) {
            $("#Modal-Charge").modal('show');
        });
    }
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052704/how-to-pass-dynamic-value-in-url-action) present a good and elegant solution but under modal doesn't work for me, the `window.location.href = url.replace('_param_', encodeURIComponent(param));` doesn't replace the parameters

Exist any other solution apart those two publish here at the post?

Thanks you

Comment: Are you having a problem using the above approach ? IF yes, what it is ?

Comment: @Shyju No, I haven't problem, Only for research and best practices